# Error in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I included angular js in my asp.net mvc project but when i call object in controller

the angular js expressions do not evaluate

here is the app.js code please suggest

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('createController', createController);
```

and here is the createController code

```
var createController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.mydata = 'I work!';
}
```

here is what i include in html

```
<html ng-app="app">
   <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/appAjs/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/appAjs/controllers/createController.js"></script>
 <div ng-controller="createController">
{{scope.mydata}}
{{6+9}}
```

Comment: And what is your question? Also just do `{{mydata}}`

Comment: the problem is the expressions do not evaluate i think there is some problem in my controller

Comment: again same problem by just doing {{mydata}}

Comment: `{{scope.mydata}}` --> `scope` is your application scope, you do not need to call it again, simply call `{{mydata}}` as the scope is already inherit... --> http://jsbin.com/zakaco/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: If `{{6+9}}` is not being evaluated to 15, then this suggests there is a problem with the angular bootstrap process - what is showing in the console?

Comment: Also, if you are minifying your code, the $scope won't work.  You need to use the syntax app.controller('createController', ['$scope', createController]);  It's a good habit to get into, because this causes huge headaches on a prod environment.

Comment: Change your `<script src="~/appAjs/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/appAjs/controllers/createController.js"></script>` to `<script src="~/appAjs/controllers/createController.js"></script><script src="~/appAjs/app.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your code, I can only suspect **two** things

- your javascript does not have the proper scope
- do not use the word `scope` in your "scope" code

---

first part: javascript scope:

Always use an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228281/28004), in your case your code should look like:

```javascript
(function(){

  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  var createController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.mydata = 'I work!';
  };


  app.controller('createController', createController);

}());
```

---

second part: don't use the word `scope`

in your HTML, you should not use the word `scope` as it's already inherit in your controller as that's the model you are passing to the "view"

hence, your code should look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="createController">
    {{mydata}}
    {{6+9}}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the result is:

```text
I work! 15
```

live code in [JSBIN so you can check it out](http://jsbin.com/zakaco/2/edit?html,js,output).

your HTML page, all together should look like this:

---

### if you have only *one file*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJs App</title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- HTML -->
  <div ng-controller="createController">
    {{mydata}}
    {{6+9}}
  </div>

  <!-- AngularJS required -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>

  <!-- AngularJS code -->
  <script>

      (function(){

        var app = angular.module('app', []);

        var createController = function ($scope) {
          $scope.mydata = 'I work!';
        };

        app.controller('createController', createController);

      }());

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

## if you're using *2 files*

file `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My AngularJs App</title>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- HTML -->
  <div ng-controller="createController">
    {{mydata}}
    {{6+9}}
  </div>

  <!-- AngularJS required -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>

  <!-- AngularJS extra files -->
  <script src="createController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

file `createController.js` (in the same folder as `index.html`)

```
      (function(){

        var app = angular.module('app', []);

        var createController = function ($scope) {
          $scope.mydata = 'I work!';
        };

        app.controller('createController', createController);

      }());
```

Comment: Maybe the problem lies in including the `createController.js` functions in the main `app.js`?

Comment: we don't have the hole code, so I would assume that he knows that part :)

Comment: @Vucko thanks it is now working but controller is in app.js but i need to create controller in separate file

Comment: @balexandre [From the last OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784547/error-in-angular-js#comment43979784_27784804), I would say that he doesn't know that part :)

Comment: @Vucko I think you're right! Then again, ohh boy!... added the same example using 2 files and explaining everything

Comment: @balexandre your updated answer will work, however, I think the OP wants to have two external files, `app.js` and `createController.js` and that he wants to import/include `createController.js` to `app.js`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may well be the order in which you are including your scripts:

Try the following:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/appAjs/controllers/createController.js"></script>
<script src="~/appAjs/app.js"></script>
```

Reasoning is that `app.js` tries to define a controller using a function that has not been defined when the function is run.

Points that `{{scope.data}}` should be `{{data}}` are correct, but do not explain `{{6+9}}` not working.

Comment: **P.S** if this works, please learn to use the javascript console. It would tell you exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the controller in the context of the app module.

Your app.js should just have

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

and your createController code should look similar to this

```
angular.module('app')
   .controller('createController', function ($scope) {
     $scope.mydata = 'I work!';
   });
```

Comment: This is wrong, `angular.module('app', [])` returns the same thing that `angular.module('app')` will return, so the code is equivalent.

Comment: could you bit explain what to do instead of what

Comment: @EdHinchliffe In order to separate app.js and the controller.js this is the way to do this though. angular.module('app', []) instantiates the module while angular.module('app') returns the singleton.

Comment: i did exactly the same what you answered but still facing problem

Comment: @user1399195 indeed, but look at the contents of app.js and controller.js in the question. controller.js includes only the controller function.

Comment: no {{6 + 9}} does not evaluate when i include controller in my html otherwise it evaluates

Comment: @KhanEngineer The javascript console should be displaying some sort of errors that can help identify the problem then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the expression from

```
{{scope.mydata}}
```

to

```
{{mydata}}
```

Expression have access to scope and no keyword is required to access a scope object.